# How do i set my Application name and logo in Paypal payment page?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal

I'm using Paypal-adaptivepayments-sdk gem, implemented the paypal transactions using ruby on rails. but didn't find any option to set my application logo or name on paypal page? Is there any way to set that?

[image: paypal page]

by default, It is setting the application name as Mr.Magorium's Wonder emporum. How do i change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, We can't put our merchant name in Sandbox mode. Whenever mode is set to production, based on the App-ID, it will automatically sets the name and logo which we have given for our Application in paypal developer login.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the SDK to use your credentials, replace the default creds with your own. From the [README](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-ruby/blob/master/README.md) in the SDK GitHub:

```
require 'paypal-sdk-adaptivepayments'
PayPal::SDK.configure(
  :mode      => "sandbox",  # Set "live" for production
  :app_id    => "APP-80W284485P519543T",
  :username  => "jb-us-seller_api1.paypal.com",
  :password  => "WX4WTU3S8MY44S7F",
  :signature => "AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A7yDhhsPUU2XhtMoZXsWHFxu-RWy" )
```

Once it is using your creds instead of the default ones, you can set this information inside of your sandbox/live account.